# Where are my app's traces/logging when running XCTest?

Tags: logging, xctest

Xcode: `Version 15.2 (15C500b)`

I only see the output from XCTest:

```
2024-02-07 09:13:13.538684-0500 PlatoUITests4SafeBox-Runner[27938:17905788] [Default] Running tests...
Test Suite 'PlatoUITests4SafeBox' started at 2024-02-07 09:13:17.355.
Test Case '-[PlatoUITests4SafeBox.PlatoUITests4SafeBox testAddEntry]' started.
    t =     0.00s Start Test at 2024-02-07 09:13:17.356
    t =     0.37s Set Up
    t =     2.51s         Setting up automation session
```

I do not see the following traces from the app. I've tried to look at other options/places inside Xcode but no luck. I've also googled it.

```
MainApp.init: Called
MainApp.init: Parsing cmdline args
MainApp.init: Error: Could not parse arguments
...
```